# AVBin in cxfreeze

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze, pyglet

I'm having a bit of trouble in Python 3 lately.

i have a program that uses Pyglet and AVBin to play sound into my game. It's one of my socket tests, so I want to test the game with someone that doesn't even own python. I used to use cx_Freeze for all of my projects, but Im having a huge problem with this one, because of pyglet and especially AVBin. I would appreciate it if anyone can give an answer to this question in a **very simple manner.** I've seen this answered a few times, but didn't get anything the people said.

Compiling for Windows 7, Python 3. AVBin and Pyglet required.

The question:
How do I compile a Python 3 script that uses AvBin and Pyglet into a Windows Executable, using cx_Freeze?

Comment: *"if anyone can give an answer"* to **what** question?!

Comment: Hi @Yooyoory, welcome to SO. For people to help you, you need to describe the problem you're having in *detail*. Explain what you've tried and what problem you're seeing. Here are some more tips on how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was my first time on Stack Exchange, I couldn't really describe the question as good as it should be. But, I researched for a few hours, and got it working! I had to upload the Pyglet library with the executable the cx_Freeze made, and also include the AVBin DLL with the executable.

I'm really sorry for asking this question in the first place. I'll make sure my next questions are more detailed.